# Automatic Duplicate file created .~db.json, Inserted contacts not fetching

Tags: reactjs, database, json-server

I've setup JSON server in root folder, while adding a new contact JSON server automatically creating .~db.json file, once closing server and restarting inserted contacts are not showing.

to communicate with json server ( GET / POST )

````
import axios from "axios";

export class ContactService {
  static ServerUrl = "http://localhost:2999";

  static getAllContacts() {
    let dataUrl = `${this.ServerUrl}/contacts`;

    return axios.get(dataUrl);
  }

  static getContact(_id) {
    let dataUrl = `${this.ServerUrl}/contacts/${_id}`;
    return axios.get(dataUrl);
  }

  static getGroups() {
    let dataUrl = `${this.ServerUrl}/groups`;
    return axios.get(dataUrl);
  }

  static getGroup(contact) {
    // console.log(contact)
    let dataUrl = `${this.ServerUrl}/groups/${contact.groupId}`;
    return axios.get(dataUrl);
  }

  static createContact (contact) {
    let dataUrl = `${this.ServerUrl}/contacts`;
    return axios.post(dataUrl, contact);
  }
}

```

After restarting json server old data fetching into project.

I've Deleted .~db.json, once new content inserted it was automatically creating.
````